# how to compare Option value without panicked in rust

Tags: rust

I define the option value like this way when the rust rocket received parameter:

```
use rocket::serde::Deserialize;
use rocket::serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq, Deserialize, Serialize)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
pub struct ChannelRequest {
    pub userId: Option<i64>,
    pub pageNum: Option<i64>,
    pub pageSize: Option<i64>,
    pub editorPick: Option<i32>
}
```

when I match the struct and compare it like this way:

```
fn find_channel(request: &ChannelRequest) -> Box<dyn BoxableExpression<crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::table, DB, SqlType=Bool> + '_> {
    use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::*;
    match request {
        ChannelRequest { editorPick, .. } if editorPick == 1 => Box::new(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::editor_pick.eq(editorPick)),
        _ => Box::new(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::editor_pick.eq(0))
    }
}
```

shows that None could not compare with integer, the error message like this:

```
thread 'rocket-worker-thread' panicked at 'called `Option::unwrap()` on a `None` value'
```

what should I do to compare the Option value with the i32 data? when the Option value is None, just make it not equal, do not throw the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am using the `unwrap_or` function to set a default value when the Option value is `None`. The code look like this:

```
fn find_channel(request: &ChannelRequest) -> Box<dyn BoxableExpression<crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::table, DB, SqlType=Bool> + '_> {
    use crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::*;
    match request {
        ChannelRequest { editorPick, .. } if editorPick.unwrap_or(0) == 1 => Box::new(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::editor_pick.eq(editorPick)),
        ChannelRequest{ minimalReputation, ..} if minimalReputation.unwrap_or(0) > 0 => Box::new(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::reputation.gt(minimalReputation)),
        _ => Box::new(crate::model::diesel::dolphin::dolphin_schema::rss_sub_source::dsl::editor_pick.eq(0))
    }
}
```